# Any tips for getting window crank to not strip?

Tags: repair

Seems like I'm replacing this crank every 6 months. I've tried cranking down the set screw, tried JB Weld, tried grinding the post to give the set screw more bite. Nothing seems to work.

Anyone have a hack they've used to success?

[image: crank]

Comment: The post the crank is on is worn out or the window is too tight.

Comment: A picture of the inside of the knurled knob the handle fits onto would be helpful.  Usually they're teethed so there is no way they can slip while turning, and the set screw is only used to keep it from sliding off.  If yours is worn down, you might need to replace the whole assembly.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and oil the hinges?  Stripping of the crank usually means too much force to open/close the window.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you open and close the window, maybe you should give the pane a little help: push when opening, pull when closing.  Might want to install a pull knob on the frame...looks like single pane glazing?

Answer (score 3):

Fix the rest of the window.

If it's stripping out every 6 months, something is bent or in need of cleaning, lubricating, or adjusting so the window operates with minimal force required.

A window crank is not intended to shove and pull with great force. If you manage to glue the crank handle on really tightly without fixing the root problem, you may crack the gearbox next (typically die-cast pot metal and not infrequently seen broken due to operating excessively hard.)